# Device support UEFI

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, mbr, gpt

I now have MBR and I want GPT.

My firmware is now Legacy(BIOS) and I want UEFI.

My firmware can boot in UEFI (option is there inside).

I have Windows 10 PRO.

Motherboad: 1949 KBC Version 90.0F

How I know if my device and motherboard support UEFI?
I found my product website - [my_product_webpage](https://support.hp.com/sk-en/product/hp-probook-450-g0-notebook-pc/5359405/model/5359407/document/c03783671)

But I cannot find information about UEFI, what / where to search about UEFI support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your processor seems to be i7 3rd gen which was launched somewhere around 2012 [ref.](https://ark.intel.com/products/63698)
HP first implemented UEFI somewhere around 2003 [ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)
I do not see any reason why your device won't  support UEFI unless you assembled it with decade old products!

Moreover since UEFI mode is there (as you said) in the firmware. Therefore I do not see any reason for your device not to support UEFI. Usually this option is only visible when there is the capability.

Side note: there are some third part softwares which can help you convert you MBR to GPT on the fly without formatting try them out but make sure you take backup first because things can go wrong anytime. 
Also pro tip: right after converting your MBR disk to GPT in the next boot immediately change firmware boot mode from `LEGACY` to `UEFI` else it won't boot!

Comment: very detailed answer and I am confiding and relaxing from your answer about my device support for UEFI. also thank you for protip because i am big amateur.

Comment: it would be great if you accept the answer if you are satisfied!

Answer (score 0):

UEFI booting offers some negligible advantages like a custom boot logo, slightly faster boot (theoretically, that is) and of course Secure Boot. Nothing special, really.

Your hardware most likely supports UEFI, as does most other hardware from the last 10 years. If you have the option in your firmware setup, support is there of course.

---

Windows actually comes with a conversion tool, `mbr2gpt`. Its intended use is in a SCCM deployment process. However, you can easily use it yourself.

1. Shut down Windows while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. Select Troubleshoot → Advanced → Command Prompt
3. Run `mbr2gpt /convert`
4. Switch to UEFI boot in the firmware setup

Of course, you should always create a backup before making changes like that.

Comment: Thank you for explanation about UEFI. Also about mbr2gpt, I will use this tool and make success with it. Very useful you mentioning it.